# installing python with pip window

Tags: python, pip

Used the standard python installation file (3.9.12) for windows.
The installation file have a built in option for pip installation:
[image]

The resulting python is without pip.
Then I try to install pip directly by using "get-pip.py" file.
This action resulted in:

> WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL,
> however the ssl module in Python is not available. WARNING: Retrying
> (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
> after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL
> because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/ WARNING:
> Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
> status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to
> HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None,
> redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not
> available.")': /simple/pip/ ERROR: Operation cancelled by user

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried to write `python -m pip` instead of just `pip` in the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Usually when I get any errors like these I will uninstall the whole Python and reinstall with all features allowed/ticked in the checkbox and it starts to work.

Answer (score 1):

You either could try  `pip3` or `python -m pip` or `python3 -m pip` you may check the installed python version. is it 3.9.12 or something else, and if it's not .12, you should set the new path to the Python with this [steps](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/08/31/how-to-change-environment-variables-on-windows-10/)

Comment: Thanks, it is 3.9.12 the pip file don't exist at all in the installation. Usually it's under python/scripts but the folder is empty.

Comment: Thanks, your up vote making me available to comment